# Is there a way for a Java application to detect if the screen is locked?

Tags: java

I'm looking for a way to know in a Java application (*without* JNI - it's a multi-platform application) can detect if the screen is locked.

For information... our application records time while a user is working - we want it to automatically stop recording when the screen is locked instead of the user having to do so explicitly.

Comment: just curious, but maybe it also leads to better answers: What is the purpose for this?

Comment: The application records time while a user is working - we want it to stop recording when the screen is locked automatically instead of them having to do so explicitly.

Comment: There was a similar need in Spark (mentioned in my answer below): Set Presence To Away When Workstation Is Locked... useful for that cross-platform IM client.

Comment: Have you found a solution? I'm having the same need today...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is an API for that or even a way to do it all. Parsing screenshots generated by java.awt.Robot is neither platform- nor version- or even configuration-independant, and in general, I don't think "screen is locked" is a well-enough defined concept to be used in this sense - on Linux, there can be more than just one "screen" (X server), you can switch to console terminals, you can have applications running one (or more) machines display their GUIs on another machine over the network...

Comment: Yep - certainly some issues, but I thought you'd be able to define "screen is locked" with respect to an application running in a specific window - whether X or Windows.

Answer (score 1):

I confirm there seems to be no Java API to detect a screen lock status.

[Spark](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/spark/) developer gave it a try in 2006 (like this [thread shows](http://www.igniterealtime.org/community/message/120674#120674)), but without giving out any details on the specific of the implementation.
However, it is likely it involved JNI and native call to functions like [WTSQuerySessionInformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383838(VS.85).aspx) (To detect if disconnected use `WTSQuerySessionInformation(NULL, WTS_CURRENT_SESSION, WTSConnectState)` and look for `WTSDisconnected`).

So, as [Michael pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450428#450459), there is no "multi-platform" universal answer (to the best of my knowledge).

Comment: so is there any way to detect on windows only say win7

Comment: @Johnydep that could be possible, but I am not aware of a  specific method for detecting the lock status on Win7