# Using java API determine calculate the time when pc is locked or kept idle

Tags: java

What i want is the time when the user locked pc. As there is sleep time which we can set but i want the time when user's pc is locked and unlocked and also the time when user 1st time logged in and last logout time.

Comment: It is most likely platform dependent, so what OS is this intended for?

Comment: Not possible using Java alone. See related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/450428/is-there-a-way-for-a-java-application-to-detect-if-the-screen-is-locked and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/614227/how-to-detect-that-a-pc-has-been-idle-for-30-seconds-using-java

Comment: You need to talk directly to Windows to do this.  Consider doing this from .NET or another native Windows technology.

Comment: I have found the solution by using Microsoft API's list we can do this... :-)

Comment: @NishantM I this seems a while ago, but can you provide more information Nishant? I have the same issue.

Comment: Also, is it possible to write the data to MS access?